# Codeigniter 3 validation run always returns false when the callback method returns TRUE

Tags: php, forms, validation, codeigniter-3

I encountered a problem while working with Codeigniter's form validation and I have no idea about what's the cause of this. Any kind of help would be appreciated

This is the login validation group:

```
    "login" => array
    (
        array
        (
            "field" => "email_address",
            "label" => "Email address",
            "rules" => array("exists", array($CI->UsersModel, "emailExists"))
        ),
    )
```

This is the method from the UsersModel class:

```
    public function emailExists($value)
    {
        $check = $this->db->select("email_address")->from("users")->where("email_address", $value)->get()->row();

        if ($check != NULL)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

I'm calling the run method here:

```
            if ($this->form_validation->run("login") == FALSE)
            {
                
            }
```

and this condition always returns false even tho the emailExists method returns TRUE if it finds the email address in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
$rules = array
    (
        array
        (
            "field" => "email_address",
            "label" => "Email address",
            "rules" => array("exists", array($CI->UsersModel, "emailExists"))
        ),
    );
```

After that and before to run validation add this line:

`$this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);`

And validate form with `run()` function **without** any parameters:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
                
}
```

**UPDATE:**

`"rules" => array("exists", array($CI->UsersModel, "emailExists"))` **is not valid!**. **Rules** must be a string which contains a list of rules separated by pipes! example:

`"rules" => 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]'`

Comment: Still same result and besides that I wanted to keep the rules in the config file